# DataAnnotation validation attributes do not work when field is rendered in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a simple model that has a string property that has validation put on it via dataannotations.
When this is rendered in the main form validation works as expected. If I move the field to a partial view the validation no longer works.

My main and partial views contain this:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyNumber)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyNumber)
```

My model looks like this:

```
  [Remote("IsValidMyNumber", "Home", 
ErrorMessage = "This does not appear to be a valid Number.")]
    public string MyNumber { get; set; }
```

Simply moving the code in the view from the view to the partial view will cause the validation to not be called.

Why is this?

Comment: The view model is remaining the same? If you inspect the rendered HTML in the two versions the outputted name of the element is the same?

Comment: Because I am rendering the partial in a @section of the page it is not being included in my Form tags. So therefore is not being validated.

Comment: Client or server side?

Comment: client thru the remote attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Because I am rendering the partial in a @section of the page it is not being included in my Form tags. So therefore is not being validated.